# Why does an anonymous function get called, whereas a named function doesn't?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, dom-events

I'm creating a CoffeeScript application that overlays a webcam video with a canvas element (this is just for context and doesn't seem to relate to my problem though). To get the proper canvas size to overlay on the video, I attach an event handler function to the `loadedmetadata` event like this:

```
WebcamWizard.prototype.initializeUserMedia = function(stream) {
  // ...
  video = document.getElementById('webcam');
  video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function(e) {
     // ...
     v = e.srcElement;
     // ...
  });
  // ...
}
```

This works nicely. However, my preference in this case goes to defining this handler method in a different method of this particular class like so:

```
WebcamWizard.prototype.initializeUserMedia = function(stream) {
   // ...
   video = document.getElementById('webcam');
   video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', this.initializeCanvas);
   // ...
}

WebcamWizard.prototype.initializeCanvas = function(e) {
   // ...
   video = e.srcElement;
   // ...
}
```

The reason I prefer this is because it makes the CoffeeScript look neater and allows me to access the canvas DOM object within the class I'm working in more easily. When I do the second however, the `initializeCanvas` method does not seem to be called. There is no error reported on the console either. Why is that?

Curiously, calling methods this way seems to work in the exact same way in the same file.

Comment: have you tried passing `WebcamWizard.initializeCanvas` instead of `this.initializeCanvas`?

Comment: Most likely you have an exception somewhere, the two call semantics shouldn't matter (unless as @jbabey suggests, there is somehow a difference at runtime between this.initializeCanvas and its prototype). You can try catching all exceptions thusly: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#js_exceptions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is probably that "initializeCanvas" will be missing a useful `this` reference when it's called after the event happens.  You're passing a reference to the function, but the `this` binding is ephemeral and will not survive.

You can wrap it in another function or use `.bind()`:

```
var wiz = this;
video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() { wiz.initializeCanvas });
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. It also showed my that I was too sloppy with this references in parts of the file. Learned something new about JS today!